# Ordenar imágenes día/noche según nombre

Tags: python, imagen, ordenamiento

Tengo un programa que ordena imágenes según la hora UTC 00:00. Las ordeno según si a las 6 y 18h es de día o es de noche. El programa aparentemente funciona bien, la cuestión está en que ordena fotos de las 21h en día o de la hora 00 o 03 en día y no sé a qué se debe. Quizá el problema resida en cómo se encuentra el valor de la hora, día o mes, me refiero a las líneas de `hora = int(get_hour(fn))` donde las tres están con (fn).

Se consiguen las horas o días o meses con el [37:39] por ejemplo porque las imágenes tienen nombres como:

```
*IR39_MSG2-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20080701151239*
```

Tengo imágenes en un intérvalo de 3 horas, por lo tanto la gracia del programa está en que hay momentos del año en que las 6 de la mñana es de noche/día y las 18 de la tarde es de noche/día, aún así, horas como las 21 tendrían que estar siempre marcadas como noche.

A ver si me pueden indicar en qué estoy fallando. Gracias y perdón por las molestias.

```
import os , time, shutil

directorio_origen = "D:/TR/Eumetsat_IR_photos/"
directorio_destino_dia = "D:/TR/IR_Photos/Daytime"
directorio_destino_noche = "D:/TR/IR_Photos/Nighttime"

def get_hour(file_name):
    return file_name[37:39]

def get_day(file_name):
    return file_name[35:37]

def get_month(file_name):
    return file_name[33:35]


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directorio_origen, topdown=False):

    for fn in files:
        path_to_file = os.path.join(root, fn)
    
        hora = int(get_hour(fn))
        dia = int(get_day(fn))
        mes = int(get_month(fn))
    
        if ((mes == 1 or mes == 2 or mes == 11 or mes == 12 and 6 < hora < 18) or
        (mes == 3 and dia < 17 and 6 < hora < 18) or (mes == 3 and dia == 17 and 6 <= hora < 18) or(mes == 3 and dia > 17 and 6 <= hora <= 18) or
        (4 <= mes <= 8 and 6 <= hora <= 18) or
        (mes == 9 and dia <= 15 and 6 <= hora <= 18) or (mes == 9 and dia >= 16 and 6 <= hora < 18) or
        (mes == 10 and dia <= 13 and 6 <= hora < 18) or (mes == 10 and dia >= 14  and 6 < hora < 18)): 
            new_directorio = directorio_destino_dia
        else:
            new_directorio = directorio_destino_noche
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(new_directorio):
                os.mkdir(new_directorio)
            shutil.copy(path_to_file, new_directorio)

        except OSError:
            print("El archivo no ha podido ser ordenado" % fn)
```

**EDITADO**

Imágenes que no se ordenan correctamente son por ejemplo: `IR39_MSG2-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20100110**21**1241` en la carpeta de día como también sucede con `IR39_MSG2-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20100111**00**1240` o `IR39_MSG2-SEVI-MSG15-0100-NA-20100104**00**1241`

Comment: Por favor, publica una lista de casos problemáticos, dando (mes, dia, hora), la clasificación que obtienes v/s el resultado correcto. Sin eso, sería adivinar.

Comment: Okay, gracias por la idea

Comment: No es una idea; sin eso la pregunta quedara cerrada por "falta de detalles".

Comment: Entiendo, gracias, ya lo puedes ver en la correción